# Определить кодировку текста .docx

Tags: кодировка

подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить кодировку прилагаемого куска текста (текст кириллический)?
Пробовал разные декодеры, ни один результата не дал. Единственное, что удалось выяснить - так это то, что тут, вероятно, не обошлось одним кодированием.
P.s. файл [[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OSAPYOei0bnIjwf2ERlGyfHuM3unQSvx/view?usp=sharing][файл]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OSAPYOei0bnIjwf2ERlGyfHuM3unQSvx/view?usp=sharing][%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB])

Comment: Это кусок Word-документа современного формата, фактически представляющий собой ZIP-файл с XML-контентом?

Comment: XML обертка есть, да. Насчет реального представления файла - не могу сказать. Но этот файл предоставлен как .docx (пособие на 2+Гб)

Comment: Так может в начале нужно распаковать или восстановить содержимое из файла document.xml, а только потом определять кодировку?

Comment: Какие декодеры, какая кодировка, Вы о чем? docx - это ZIP-архив, внутри несколько XML (и опционально - других файлов, например .jpg). Все XML там в UTF-8.

Comment: Yaant опредленно прав. Я забыл, что по стандарту там кодовая страница файла 65001/UTF-8